# sms/imessage's allert don't work for one contact

Tags: ios, messages, alert

I have an iPhone 11 on 13.5.1 iOs. Suddenly, the alerts of imessage don't work, for one only person. There is no budge for new message in the chat (on the main app, where all the chats are).
This specific contact is not on the "Do not disturb" and the alerts are on, but my iPhone neither rings nor has a banner for the new message. I've already tried to delete the chat, delete the contact, restore the settings but nothing of these worked. What can i do?
Thanks in advance.

Edit: when I open the message from this contact, he cannot see if I read the message or not. The status of the message is “delivered”.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Ask Different. So you don't get any alert but you do receive the message, is that right? Is it an SMS or an iMessage?

Comment: That's right. I receive the imessage but there is no alert!

Answer (score 1):

is it possible that you have muted or limited the alert on this contact?

[image: Hide Alerts on ios contacts via imessage]

Or, if you have added them to the Spam or Block, then alerts would be suppressed.

https://www.igeeksblog.com/how-to-block-someone-on-imessage-on-iphone/

1. Open the Settings app → Scroll down and tap on Messages.
2. Tap on Settings then Messages on iPhone
3. Now, scroll down again and tap on Blocked → To check a person from this list

You can unblock them by taping on Settings → Messages → Blocked → Edit → Tap on Red minus sign → Tap on Unblock → Finally tap on Done.

[image: unblock ios messages]